# Check a field is contains in another list in ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, contains

I have a list called `@domianskill_technical_skills`. This table is related table for **domain_skills** and **technical_skills** data and is retrieved based on **domain_skill_id**

I need return all technical_skills from the **technical_skills** table but have one more attribute named **assigned** which is true if the `technical_skill_id` is present in the `@domianskill_technical_skills` list.

My working code is like below

```
def assigned_technical_skills

      @domain_skill_technical_skills = DomainSkillsTechnicalSkill.select('id, technical_skill_id').where(domain_skill_id: params[:domain_skill_id])

      Rails.logger.info(@domain_skill_technical_skills.to_a)

      TechnicalSkill.all.where(record_status: 1).each do |skill|

        if @domain_skill_technical_skills.include?(skill.id) then
          Rails.logger.info(skill.id.to_s + skill.name)
        end

      end

      respond_with @domain_skill_technical_skills
  end
```

Please guide me to correct the if statement and also need to select the needed fields (id, name, assigned) and create one instance for return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to replace your code with this, if DomainSkillsTechnicalSkill has 'technical_skill_id' column

```
def assigned_technical_skills
  # just collect technical_skill_id 
  @domain_skill_technical_skill_ids = DomainSkillsTechnicalSkill.select('id, technical_skill_id').where(domain_skill_id: params[:domain_skill_id]).collect(&:technical_skill_id)
  Rails.logger.info(@domain_skill_technical_skill_ids.to_a)
  @technical_skills = []  
  TechnicalSkill.select('id, name').where(record_status: 1).each do |skill|

    @technical_skills << skill.as_json.merge!(
      { assigned: @domain_skill_technical_skill_ids.include?(skill.id)}
    )       
  end
  respond_with @technical_skills
end
```

Comment: `//` should become `#`

Comment: thanks but assigned is not a field in the table. I need to add as additional. Now i got **Unknown column 'assigned' in 'field list'**. Also i got the mapped data only.

Comment: @Akhil updated answer can you check, if its working?

Comment: @PramodShinde i just checked and got the error **NoMethodError (undefined method `merge!' for #<Array:0x00000003f20028>):**. And also i think you only select the mapped technical_skills only. I need all technical_skills but assigned is with true and others with false

Comment: @PramodShinde thanks a lot. It worked for mapped data but i need all technical_skills. If mapped data not found i need 'assigned field as false. Please guide

Comment: @Akhil can you check now?

Comment: @PramodShinde thanks .. please correct spelling mistake in logger method.