# Using Arrays in Rabl

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I am returning a collection from the query. The query is in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817975/check-a-field-is-contains-in-another-list-in-ror).

So my result is like below in my log:

```
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"ASP.NET-WebForms", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:04:18 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:04:18 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"Serverside-Framework", :assigned=>true}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"ASP.NET-MVC", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:05:01 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:05:01 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"Serverside-Framework", :assigned=>true}, {"id"=>3, "name"=>"RUBY-ON-RAILS", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:05:20 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:05:20 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"Serverside-Framework", :assigned=>false}, {"id"=>4, "name"=>"C#", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>2, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:05:57 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:12:02 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"Language", :assigned=>false}, {"id"=>5, "name"=>"Ruby", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:07:43 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:07:43 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"Language", :assigned=>true}, {"id"=>6, "name"=>"VB", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:08:15 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:08:15 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"Language", :assigned=>false}, {"id"=>7, "name"=>"SQL-Server", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:08:32 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:08:32 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"DBMS", :assigned=>false}, {"id"=>8, "name"=>"MySQL", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:08:49 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:08:49 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"DBMS", :assigned=>false}, {"id"=>9, "name"=>"Oracle", "description"=>"", "record_status"=>1, "created_by"=>1, "updated_by"=>1, "created_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:09:01 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 23 Apr 2015 06:09:01 UTC +00:00, "skill_type"=>"DBMS", :assigned=>false}]
```

I think this is an array instead of an object collection. So how can I display this as json using rabl. The collection @technical_skills is not working.

My expected output is:

```
{
    "domain_skill": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "domain name",
        "description": "some description text",
        "technical_skills": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ASP.NET-WebForms",
                "assigned": true
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "ASP.NET-MVC",
                "assigned": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Edit:

I got that this is a json array. My method to merge another field so that I can convert this to json and merge the new fields. Now I thought this is json array. Please check my controller method below:

```
    id = params[:id]
    @domain_skill_technical_skill_ids = DomainSkillsTechnicalSkill.select('id, technical_skill_id').where(domain_skill_id: id).collect(&:technical_skill_id)
    Rails.logger.info(@domain_skill_technical_skill_ids.to_a)
    @technical_skills = []
    TechnicalSkill.select('id, name').where(record_status: 1).each do |skill|

      @technical_skills << skill.as_json.merge!(
          { assigned: @domain_skill_technical_skill_ids.include?(skill.id)}
      )
    end
@domain_skill_view_model = DomainSkillViewModel.new(@domain_skill, @technical_skills)
    respond_with @domain_skill_view_model
```

My `rabl`:

```
object :@domain_skill_view_model

object :@domain_skill
attributes :id, :name, :description

node :technical_skills do
  @technical_skills.each do |skill|

  end
end
```

Comment: I finished using loop in node. I will put as answer when allowed

Comment: I need some more.. i can't fix specific fields in rabl. please help. I updated my rabl in the question